# Difference between "sqoop-merge --merge-key" and "sqoop --import --merge-key"

Tags: hadoop, merge, sqoop, bigdata

Difference between `sqoop-merge --merge-key` and `sqoop --import --merge-key` is just that `sqoop-merge --merge-key` will save the incremental data into hdfs first and  then merge with the old datas, whereas the `sqoop --import --merge-key` will load the new data and merge the data with the old data directly?

If my old data is too big to merge, which way to update the old data is better?

Now my old data is about 40GB, and when I use `sqoop --import --merge-key` to update data, it takes longer then I load all data directly. Sometimes it will result in failure of the mapreduce jobs because of the usage of RAM. So, could I have some optimization to deal with this?

Comment: 40GB is not too big for a typical Hadoop cluster to handle. Do you know how much RAM your program is allocated to use? How much is total memory allocated for Yarn?